# Objective Sharpie fails with errors originating in the SDK's header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, objective-sharpie

I am trying to bind an Objective-C library and I have successfully generated the binaries. However, when using Objective Sharpie, I get a list of errors that seem to be originating inside the iOS SDK. I launch the following command:

```
sharpie bind --output RealtimeSharp --namespace Realtime --sdk iphoneos9.0 ./Realtime/OrtcClient.h
```

and I get the following output:

```
Parsing Native Code...
In file included from /Users/Umar/Documents/Projects/Realtime/Realtime/OrtcClient.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:19:21: error: 
      expected a type
- (id)copyWithZone:(nullable NSZone *)zone;
                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:25:28: error: 
      expected a type
- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(nullable NSZone *)zone;
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:32:4: error: 
      expected a type
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder; // NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:53:4: error: 
      expected a type
- (nullable id)replacementObjectForCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:54:4: error: 
      expected a type
- (nullable id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_REPLACES_RECEIVER;
   ^
In file included from /Users/Umar/Documents/Projects/Realtime/Realtime/OrtcClient.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:7:15: error: 
      expected ';' after @class
@class NSArray<ObjectType>;
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:7:16: error: 
      cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
@class NSArray<ObjectType>;
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:25: error: 
      cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:37: error: 
      expected identifier or '('
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:36:4: error: 
      expected a type
- (nullable ObjectType)nextObject;
   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:25: error: 
      cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:1: error: 
      duplicate interface definition for class 'NSEnumerator'
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:12: note: 
      previous definition is here
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:37: error: 
      method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:38: error: 
      expected a type
@interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:1: error: 
      expected selector for Objective-C method
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:28: error: 
      unknown type name 'NSArray'
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:35: error: 
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
                           ~~~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:1: error: 
      property requires fields to be named
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
^                          ~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:35: error: 
      expected ';' at end of declaration list
@property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
                                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
Error while processing /Users/Umar/Documents/Projects/Realtime/Realtime/OrtcClient.h.

Submitting usage data to Xamarin...
  Submitted - thank you for helping to improve Objective Sharpie!

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: Clang failed to parse input and exited with code 1
```

My list of SDKs (`sharpie xcode -sdks`):

```
sdk: iphoneos9.0          arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: macosx10.11          arch: x86_64  i386
sdk: watchos2.0           arch: 
sdk: watchsimulator2.0    arch:
```

My Objective Sharpie version is (`sharpie --version`):

```
2.1.6p 6e2f8ea 6e2f8ea5ac2f544c58938555a06ef21a4ecb032a 2015-03-17 17:39:55
```

And my Xamarin Studio's version is 5.9.7 (build 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xamarin says](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/156524/#Comment_156524) it's an Objective Sharpie's bug, so they will be releasing a new version soon.

Answer (score 1):

I can generate binding successfully after adding `-xobjective-c` after the `-c argument`.
Somethings like:

`sharpie bind -output Binding -sdk iphoneos9.2 -scope build/Headers build/Headers/Example/Example.h -c -xobjective-c -Ibuild/Headers -arch arm64`

My Sharpie version is 3.0.8.

Comment: its not downvoted by me... someone else might have done, who thinks that this answer is incomplete